# PHP display dynamically populated variable in separate code block

Tags: php, css

I have a php loop that loads some images onto some slider:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">

foreach($imglist as $image) {

$caption =  // I am populating this variable from the image meta data

echo '<li><img src="'.$img_folder.$image.'">';
}
</ul>
</div>
<div id="caption-block" class="myNewDiv">
<p>
echo $caption;
</p>
</div>
```

I am also pulling meta data from the image and loading each meta data. My question has to do with the fact that I would like to load the caption outside of the  in which the loop resides onto a separate . As you can probably infer, the code I have written does not work because $caption is not dynamically loaded as it's not inside the loop.

Is it possible to have the $caption which is on a separate div be populated dynamically with php? If so, what's the best approach?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I think you want to change `$caption =` to `$image`

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misguided, I will work on further elaborating the question. What I want to do is populate the $caption inside the <div class="myNewDiv">, which is outside of the loop that initializes that variable.

Comment: You'll need to output the HTML in the loop as well.

Comment: I see, I was thinking that'd be the case, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Is the caption just a single element and the variable a string? If so I don't see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to dynamically inject the caption into the `#caption-block` div using a Flexslider callback. In that case, you could store the caption in a data attribute of the img tag and then pull it out using a custom function in the Flexslider before: callback. Here's the HTML/PHP:

```
<?php echo '<li><img src="'.$img_folder.$image.'" data-caption="'.$caption.'">'; ?>
```

Inside the Flexslider before: callback:

```
before: function(slider){
    // set current slide 
    var currSlide = slider.slides.eq(slider.animatingTo + 1);
    var caption = $(currSlide).find("img").data('caption');
    $('#caption-block p').text(caption);
}
```